# selenium-server-standalone first start windows 10

Tags: php, selenium, yii2

I'm trying to start use selenium server with my Yii2 project.
I successfully installed selenium-server-standalone on win 10 with that command:

```
composer global require se/selenium-server-standalone
```

But when I try to start selenium-server-standalone I have error message::

```
sh is no internal or external
command, operable program or batch file.
```

There is java and selenium in my PATH, also I have a selenium-server-standalone.bat file in `C:\Users\***\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor.`
Please, tell me how can I solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have mentioned you are trying to run selenium server on Win10 machine and error you are facing is `sh is no internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

Seems you are typing `sh selenium-server-standalone.bat` in your command. that is for Linux.

For windows machine, simply go to your path where batch file is located (`C:\Users\***\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor`) , type `selenium-server-standalone.bat` and hit enter. Selenium server will start.